# How to go next page after click on success message?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages Home.aspx and Master.aspx respectively. I am using message box for success messages. Now I want to go next page (from Home.aspx to Master.aspx) when I click the 'ok' button of message box. My message box code is,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Employee Details  Already Added In this ID ..!!');", true);
```

It shows success message but I do not know how to redirect this page to next page when click on 'ok' button.

Comment: Well, define an `onClick` event handler on that button and do whatever you want in that event handler, most probably use an `Response.Redirect()`

Comment: Bartdude , can you show me an example

Comment: Nope, you have to do some research. It's quite a trivial behavior and what yopu're trying to achieve could be done both server-side or client-side depending on your needs so there's not 1 single solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `window.location` to navigate from current url to another.

Your script should look like this:

```
alert('Employee Details  Already Added In this ID ..!!'); window.location='/master.aspx';
```

Comment: brz, I am using web application so I couldnt find window.location property

Comment: that's because this answers uses Javascript (client-side)... But still this will do exactly what you ask for without any roundtrip to the server which is good if you don't need it (ie: if you don't need to do any server-side tracking or database update when the user clicks the button)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine..

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Leave Type Added Succesfully ..!!');window.location='Leavetypedetail.aspx';", true);
```